# Rewrite MYSQL query using Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to rewrite MYSQL query using Laravel query builder

So this is the query

```
DB::select("SELECT * FROM accomodation WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT accomodation_id FROM bookings
WHERE (`checkin` <= '$request->in' AND  `checkout` >= '$request->out'));");
```

And this is what I've done so far

```
Accommodation::whereNotIN('id', function($q)
  {
    $q->select('accomodation_id')
    ->from('bookings')
    ->where('checkin', '<=', '$request->out')
    ->where ('checkout', '>=', '$request->in');
  })
->get();
```

The problem is the first query is giving me expected results but the second one isn't

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have your In's and Out's the wrong way round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you type it wrong. Look at the `$request->in` and `$request->out`. You may want to flip it. and why you use `'$request->in'` instead of `$request->in`. It will parse as string instead of the value

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `use`. For example `php Accommodation::whereNotIN('id', function($q) use ($request)` and you need to flip condition with request ;)